# Application not validating user when using prepared statement

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

I was originally using the below code to validate a user login which worked

```
 public static boolean validate(String name, String password) {
        boolean status = false;
        try {
            Connection con = DB.getConnection();
            String select = "select * from Librarian where UserName= '" + name + "' and Password='"+ password +"'";
            Statement selectStatement = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = selectStatement.executeQuery(select);
          
            status = rs.next();
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return status;
    }
```

I seen that using a prepared statement is better and the one above is vulnerable to SQL injection. Below is my code im trying to use

```
public static boolean validate(String name, String password) {
        boolean status = false;
        try {
            Connection con = DB.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from Librarian where UserName= ? and password = ?");
            ps.setString(1, name);
            ps.setString(2, password);       
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return status;
    }
```

This isnt validating the user and im unable to access the application. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You forgot `status = rs.next();` in the second block.

Comment: Note that (1) you should _never_ store passwords in a database (use a **password** hash instead), and (2) except for educational purposes, you should not write your own security code; instead, use libraries that have already been reviewed by the community.

Comment: would using a password hash affect the validation code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the **status = rs.next();**

```
public static boolean validate(String name, String password) {
  boolean status = false;
  try {
    Connection con = DB.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from Librarian where UserName= ? and password = ?");
    ps.setString(1, name);
    ps.setString(2, password);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    status = rs.next();
    con.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
  }
  return status;
}
```

Comment: Thats worked thanks, I knew it was something small